# Merge and remove and then duplicate row

Tags: pandas, csv, merge

I have a df with the sectional times that horses run for a race. For every race, it has a line called 'Race_Leader'. This isn't an actual horse, it is just data for the race leader of the race. I would like 'Race_Leader' row to be removed and I would like it to be duplicated so that every 'HorseId' has corresponding data for the race leader of that race. Please see the example below of my desired output.

FYI, 'HorseId' always = 0 for 'Race_Leader'

Example of df:

```
HorseId    Name             RaceId    Sectionals
0          Race_Leader      123       41.3
224        Winx             123       42.4
225        Black Caviar     123       41.3
226        Rekindling       123       44.4
227        Fabergino        123       43.2
```

Desired output:

```
HorseId    Name             RaceId    Sectionals  RL Sectionals 
224        Winx             123       42.4           41.3
225        Black Caviar     123       41.3           41.3
226        Rekindling       123       44.4           41.3
227        Fabergino        123       43.2           41.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a mask, both to [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a new column after [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html), and then to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['Name'].eq('Race_Leader')

out = df.assign(**{'RL Sectionals': df['Sectionals'].where(m).ffill()})[~m]
```

*NB. if you have several rows with "Race_Leader", the "RL Sectionals" value for a given row will always be that of the preceding race leader.*

Output:

```
   HorseId          Name  RaceId  Sectionals  RL Sectionals
1      224          Winx     123        42.4           41.3
2      225  Black Caviar     123        41.3           41.3
3      226    Rekindling     123        44.4           41.3
4      227     Fabergino     123        43.2           41.3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df['RL Sectionals'] = df.groupby('RaceId')['Sectionals'].transform('min')
df[df['Name'].ne('Race_Leader')]
```

output:

```
    HorseId    Name             RaceId    Sectionals  RL Sectionals 
1    224        Winx             123       42.4           41.3
2    225        Black Caviar     123       41.3           41.3
3    226        Rekindling       123       44.4           41.3
4    227        Fabergino        123       43.2           41.3
```